# my vector is of type <T*>, how do i now get to its value when using the iterator?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have an Asteroid class:

```
class Asteroid
{
public:
    Asteroid();

    float GetMovementSpeed();
    float GetRotationSpeed();

    Placement^ GetCurrentOrientation();
    void UpdateOrientation( Placement^ placement );

    float GetPosX();
    float GetPosY();
    float GetPosZ();

    float GetRotX();
    float GetRotY();
    float GetRotZ();
private:
    float movementSpeed;
    float rotationSpeed;

    Placement^ placement;

    //float x;
    //float y;
    //float z;

    //float rotX;
    //float rotY;
    //float rotZ;
};
```

I have set up the following vector and filled it up with Asteroids :) ...

```
vector<Asteroid*> asteroids;

asteroids.push_back( new Asteroid() );
asteroids.push_back( new Asteroid() );
asteroids.push_back( new Asteroid() );

for(std::vector<Asteroid*>::iterator asteroid = asteroids.begin(); asteroid != asteroids.end(); ++asteroid) 
{
    asteroid-> //Can't access the methods of the asteroid class?
}
```

But inside the iterator, asteroid does not have access to the methods of the asteroid class. What am I missing out?

Comment: What do you mean by can't access the methods?

Answer (score 5):

An iterator acts like a pointer. Your type is also a pointer. What you have to do is first "dereference" the iterator and then use the pointer:

```
(*asteroid)->doSomething();
```

Comment: Of course (but don't forget the damn time limit, curse you stackoverflow answer acceptance time limit do-raggy) Oh no he didn't!